# Calling intent in onResume leads to infinite recursion

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to call an intent to another app everytime I might have left my app. This means that everytime I (re-start) my `MainActivity` I need to call this intent in the `onResume`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setData(Uri.parse("protocol://mycall.stuff"));
intent.setAction("protocol.GET");
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

The problem is that this intent leads to `onActivityResult` which seems to call `onResume` again when it's done and so on.

I tried to use `finish()` after my `onActivityResult` like it was suggested in some other posts but then my activity - well - finishes.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: `I need to call this intent in the onResume` - Can't you call it in onStop? or, even better, in onDestroy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `boolean` to handle this situation as below...

```
boolean done = false;

@Override
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    if (!done) {

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("protocol://mycall.stuff"));
        intent.setAction("protocol.GET");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

        done = true;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Android has onResume state in its life cycle, so you can't prevent calling onResume when you create an activity. What you can do is to control it by a flag to prevent calling the task inside onResume by if(flag) return;